# ¿ Cómo convertir la primer letra en Mayúscula y las restantes en minúsculas con Angular?

Tags: angular

Necesito convertir la palabra escrita en el `input text` de tal forma que quede solo la primer letra en mayúscula y las restantes en minúsculas.
Ejemplo:

"esta es la cadena" => (convertir a) "Esta es la cadena"

"eSTa Es La cAdenA"  => (convertir a) "Esta es la cadena"

"cadena" => (convertir a) "Cadena"

Hice esto, pero no da resultado

en el `componente.ts`

```js
firstLetterUpperCase (word: string){
    return word.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, c => c.toUpperCase());
  }
  
  updateCategory(form: Ngform){
     const a = this.firstLetterUpperCase(this.categoryEdit.name);
     console.log(a);
  
  }
```

Aca en el `componente.html`

```html
<form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateCategory()">
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="editedName" 
  [(ngModel)]="categoryEdit.name"
  (blur)="categoryEdit.name = cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(categoryEdit.name)"
  class="form-control"
  maxlength="50" 
  placeholder={{c.name}}>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1" type="submit">Update</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-1" type="button" (click)="editing =false">Cancelar</button>
 </div>                         
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, puedes rescatar la cadena deseada, y asignarla a una variable.
Llamaremos a esta cadena "`string`" para ejemplificar.
Usando `substr` podemos obtener la primera letra y el resto.
Además, podemos darle a mayusculas y minusculas de inmediato.

```
var string = "AJSHNasjdkaASDHl";
var mayus = string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
var resto = string.substring(1, string.lenght).toLowerCase();
mayus.concat(resto.toString());
//Output: Ajshnasjdkaasdhl
```

Comment: Si, disculpa, fue mi error, olvide que era typescript. Listo ahora si deberia funcionar

Comment: Gracias, tu código ahora no tiene errores, pero mi variable que esta en  [(ngModel)]="categoryEdit.name" cuando se la paso a la función (con tu código) no me convierte nada

Comment: esta es la funcion, donde le agregue el return  firstLetterUpperCase (str: string){
    var mayus = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    var resto = str.substring(1, str.length).toLowerCase();
    return mayus.concat(resto.toString());
  }

Comment: y aca le paso a esa funcion, la variable que esta con ngModel  this.firstLetterUpperCase(this.editCategory.name);

Comment: La variable de que tipo es? Como llega la cadena?

Comment: Lo otro, es que crees otra pregunta con el nuevo codigo, asi poder entender realmente como esta todo.,

Comment: Que raro, si la cadena es string, no deberia haber problema. Crea una nueva publicacion por que el problema ha cambiado

Comment: Gracias, tenia un error en la funcion firstLetterUpperCase() ya que le estaba pasando por parametro otra variable. Lo acabo de corregir en la publicacion, la forma correcta era  const a = this.firstLetterUpperCase(this.categoryEdit.name);

Comment: Ahhh viste, si tenia que ser con la variable, dado que revise que aceptara string en todas sus formas

Answer (score 1):

Tambien se puede tratar el string como `Array`, es solo una alternativa, te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
const str = `eSTa Es La cAdenA`;
const result = `${a[0].toUpperCase()}${a.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;
```

Te dejo una tabla de comparación.

[image: comparación]

Saludos